# Adding constraints on an existing textLabel in custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints, ios-autolayout

I wanted to add a simple counter of the number of objects in the table in the table header, next to its textLabel. So I created this class:

```
import UIKit

class CounterHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)

    var counterLabel: UILabel

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        counterLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(counterLabel)

        counterLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        counterLabel.backgroundColor = .red

        if let textLabel = self.textLabel{
            counterLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 6.0).isActive = true
            counterLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
            counterLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0).isActive = true
        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        counterLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

But running this results in the following error:

```
'Unable to activate constraint with anchors 
<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x60000388ae00 "UILabel:0x7fb8314710a0.leading"> 
and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x60000388ae80 "_UITableViewHeaderFooterViewLabel:0x7fb8314718c0.trailing"> 
because they have no common ancestor.  
Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  
That's illegal.'
```

How can I add a constraint for my counterLabel based on the already existing textLabel? Isn't textLabel already a subview of ContentView?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use built-in `textLabel`, which I'm pretty sure isn't available at the `init` time. Try to execute your layouting code inside `layoutSubviews` method, right after `super` call. The method could be evaluated a couple of times, so you should check if you've already layouted your view (e.g. `couterLabel.superview != nil`)

here's how it should looks like:

```
final class CounterHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    static let reuseIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)

    let counterLabel = UILabel()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if counterLabel.superview == nil {
            layout()
        }
    }

    func layout() {
        contentView.addSubview(counterLabel)
        counterLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        counterLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        if let textLabel = self.textLabel {
            counterLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 6.0).isActive = true
            counterLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true
            counterLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Should I override the layoutSubviews() method for this view and put the layouting code inside it? 
If I do it IT is run just after the init() and the textLabel still is not available (I'm getting the same error).

Comment: updated the answer with a code example. just tested it in a fresh project, looks good. let me know if it's not for you